# How to lint typos in color names in stylelint?

Tags: stylelint

Is it possible to have stylelint detect when I have a typo in a named color? Like detecting that `color: pruple` is wrong, the real color name being `purple`.

So far I can only find rules for forcing all colors to be hex/alpha/named, but no check to validate the actual named values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to have stylelint detect when I have a typo in a named color?

Yes, by using the [csstree-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-csstree-validator) plugin. It will validate the property-value pairs of declarations, including those where the value can contain [`<color>` types](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-4/#named-colors).

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "stylelint-csstree-validator"
  ],
  "rules": {
    "csstree/validator": true
  }
}
```